# Implication of specialist step order

Tags: unity-of-command

In the *Unity of Command* manual, when discussing specific combat calculations example (see image below), it is stated so:

> **Specialist Step Loss:** 4 red Xs on the combat sheet show that all Soviet losses will be absorbed by regular steps because NKVD is in position 5. If the same unit is attacked again however, the NKVD will be first in line to take a loss.

[image: Unity of Command example combat projection]

Does it mean if it is attacked in the same turn, or at any of the subsequent turns? How does suppression factor into this? For instance, if on the next attack specialist step is suppressed, and then the next attack after that causes one or two losses, will it affect the suppressed steps first or only those active steps actually participating in combat, thus sparing the specialist? In that case, is the order of steps changes?

Also, does it mean that the most beneficial position for the specialist is the last, eighth step for the full-strength seven step regular, and for that reason it should be returned into the force pool via reorganization if the unit it’s currently attached to suffers heavy casualties to prevent its loss, so it can be re-attached to a stronger unit later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specialist steps position themselves at the start of each turn.  So in the example from the manual, the first combat causes 4 losses.  If the Soviet unit suffered addition losses in the same turn, the NKVD step would be the first lost.  If the NKVD step survives the turn, it will be positioned per the chart on p33 of the manual.

Suppressed steps are always at the end and are only lost if there are no active steps (see p14).  And per the manual (p33 again) suppressed specialist steps are always placed after suppressed regular steps.  So if the NKVD were suppressed, it would be moved to (and stay at) the end of the line and only be lost if no other steps were present.

You never get to choose where the specialist step is among the unit's steps.  You'd have to reorganize or detach the step before the specialist step is lost.